# Descobrir se alguma coisa mudou no formulário usando jQuery

Tags: jquery

Olá, gostaria de saber se há algum método no jQuery que retorne se houve mudanças no formulário inicial ou não.
Por exemplo, tenho 3 campos vazios, e assim que eu modificar algum deles. o jQuery me retornar algo...

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa de jQuery.

```
document.getElementById('campo').addEventListener('input', function () {
    /* faz alguma coisa */
});
```

Você pode usar `change` no lugar de `input` se você quiser que o seu código só seja executado quando o usuário sair do campo.

Se você quiser fazer isso pra todo mundo, você pode fazer

```
var toArray = Array.prototype.slice.call;
function doSomething() {
    /* faz alguma coisa */
}
toArray(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')).forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('input', doSomething);
});
```

Aí ali no `querySelectorAll` você pode restringir só a alguns inputs, se você quiser checkboxes, se você quiser só os inputs de um certo formulário…

Comment: Vou testar, mas não sei se é isso exatamente que quero, pois, no lugar de 'campo' eu deveria especificar o id de um dos campos não?
Eu queria uma forma global, em qualquer lugar que o usuário modificasse no meu documento eu descobrisse (Não sei se fui claro).

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode também usar a função change do jQuery, ficaria assim:

```
$(':input').change(function(){  
  //Ação desejada.
});
```

Neste pequeno exemplo marquei pra selecionar todos os campos INPUT, mas você pode através do seletor do jQuery selecionar os campos desejados.

Em Ação desejada, você coloca o código a ser executado quando um usuário modifica o campo selecionado, como por exemplo dar um feedback de que o campo foi preenchido.